# Save two point clouds

Tags: point-clouds, open3d

I am trying to merge two point clouds.

The below code is the implementation of global registration from Open3d.

It takes two point clouds as input, performs RANSAC and ICP and visualizes the two point clouds with transformation.

```
    import copy

import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
temp1=1
temp2=2


def draw_registration_result(source, target, transformation):
    source_temp= copy.deepcopy(source)
    target_temp = copy.deepcopy(target)
    source_temp.paint_uniform_color([1, 0.706, 0])
    target_temp.paint_uniform_color([0, 0.651, 0.929])
    source_temp.transform(transformation)
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_temp, target_temp],
                                     )


def preprocess_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size):
    print(":: Downsample with a voxel size %.3f." % voxel_size)
    pcd_down = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size)

    radius_normal = voxel_size * 2
    print(":: Estimate normal with search radius %.3f." % radius_normal)
    pcd_down.estimate_normals(
        o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=radius_normal, max_nn=30))

    radius_feature = voxel_size * 5
    print(":: Compute FPFH feature with search radius %.3f." % radius_feature)
    pcd_fpfh = o3d.pipelines.registration.compute_fpfh_feature(
        pcd_down,
        o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=radius_feature, max_nn=100))
    return pcd_down, pcd_fpfh

def prepare_dataset(voxel_size):
    print(":: Load two point clouds and disturb initial pose.")
    source = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("bin1.ply")
    target = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("bin2.ply")


    #source.estimate_normals(
        #search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=0.1, max_nn=30))
    #target.estimate_normals(
    #search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=0.1, max_nn=30))
    trans_init = np.asarray([[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                             [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
    #source.transform(trans_init)
    draw_registration_result(source, target, np.identity(4))

    source_down, source_fpfh = preprocess_point_cloud(source, voxel_size)
    target_down, target_fpfh = preprocess_point_cloud(target, voxel_size)
    return source, target, source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh

voxel_size = 0.05 # means 5cm for this dataset
source, target, source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh = prepare_dataset(
    voxel_size)


def execute_global_registration(source_down, target_down, source_fpfh,
                                target_fpfh, voxel_size):
    distance_threshold = voxel_size * 1.5
    print(":: RANSAC registration on downsampled point clouds.")
    print("   Since the downsampling voxel size is %.3f," % voxel_size)
    print("   we use a liberal distance threshold %.3f." % distance_threshold)
    result = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_ransac_based_on_feature_matching(
        source_down, target_down, source_fpfh, target_fpfh, True,
        distance_threshold,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint(False),
        3, [
            o3d.pipelines.registration.CorrespondenceCheckerBasedOnEdgeLength(
                0.9),
            o3d.pipelines.registration.CorrespondenceCheckerBasedOnDistance(
                distance_threshold)
        ], o3d.pipelines.registration.RANSACConvergenceCriteria(100000, 0.999))
    return result
result_ransac = execute_global_registration(source_down, target_down,
                                            source_fpfh, target_fpfh,
                                            voxel_size)
print(result_ransac)
draw_registration_result(source_down, target_down, result_ransac.transformation)


def refine_registration(source, target, source_fpfh, target_fpfh, voxel_size):
    distance_threshold = voxel_size * 0.4
    print(":: Point-to-plane ICP registration is applied on original point")
    print("   clouds to refine the alignment. This time we use a strict")
    print("   distance threshold %.3f." % distance_threshold)
    result = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
        source, target, distance_threshold, result_ransac.transformation,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPlane())
    return result
result_icp = refine_registration(source, target, source_fpfh, target_fpfh,
                                 voxel_size)
print(result_icp)
draw_registration_result(source, target, result_icp.transformation)
```

How to save the resultant source_temp and target_temp as a single pointcloud?

Comment: I think making `source_temp` and `target_temp` globals just makes everything way more confusing than it has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Open3d, you can just combine two point clouds into one using the `+` operator, and save the result ([Source](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/pipelines/multiway_registration.html?highlight=combine#Make-a-combined-point-cloud)):

```
pcd_combined = source_temp + target_temp
o3d.io.write_point_cloud("combined_point_cloud.pcd", pcd_combined)
```

Note: I agree with the comment above that making the point clouds global makes the code confusing and could lead to unexpected results.